# wget does not download files on Amazon AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, wget

I was trying to download all the slides from the following webpage

> ```
> https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/NLPCourseraSlides.html
> ```

The command I was using was

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-proxy -r -l 3 'https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/NLPCourseraSlides.html'
```

I could only download html and some PNG files. Those slides are hosted on Amazon S3 but I could not crawl them using the command above. The message showing on the terminal is

I could, however, download those slides directly using a command below

```
wget http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/nlp/slides/intro.pdf
```

Anybody knows why? How do I download all the slides on that page using a single command?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is called "HTML Scraping". This means that you take an HTML page and then parse the HTML links inside the page. After parsing you can download, catalog, etc. the links found in the document (web page).

This StackOverflow article is very popular for this topic:

[Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: I thought the "-r" option and "-l" option for wget were for that, isn't it?

Comment: You will need to consult the documentation for the version of wget that you are using. There are many clones of wget. Not all support the same options. Not all clones can process recursive downloads for all types of HTML pages. If you have a test case that does not work, use a different version or report a bug.

Comment: I used the same command on the same machine to download files from this site: http://www.mmds.org/#ver21. My version of wget comes with CentOS7 so there should not be a problem on the software.